# Plotting custom periodic function

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a periodic function with following commands:

```
x[t_] := 1 + t /; -Pi < t <  Pi
x1[t_] := x[Mod[t, 2 Pi]]
Plot[x1[t],{t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

but in the figure, the function has not been plotted in [-Pi, 0].
[image]

Comment: Mod function gives remainder of division by 2Pi. Hence, the region of interest is (0,2Pi)+n(2Pi), where n is an Integer. I suppose this is a solution you sought `x1[t_] := x[Mod[t + Pi, 2 Pi] - Pi]`

Answer (score 5):

```
x[t_] := 1 + t /; -Pi < t < Pi
x1[t_] := x[Mod[t + Pi, 2 Pi] - Pi]
Plot[x1[t], {t, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[-4, 4]*Pi, Automatic}, ImageSize -> 400, 
 Ticks -> {Pi Range[-4, 4], Automatic}, Exclusions -> True, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Thin, Black, Dashed]]
```

[image]

### Edit

As @march suggested in the comment below, a third, `Offset` argument can be supplied to `Mod` which will give the same effect.

`x1[t_]:= x[Mod[t,2Pi,Pi]]`

Comment: `Mod` takes a third argument that allows you to do the same thing: i.e. do `Mod[t, 2 Pi, -Pi]` instead of `Mod[t + Pi, 2 Pi] - Pi`.

Comment: To be honest, I've never looked documentation for `Mod`. It seamed too straightforward...